# Sampling from a specific part of a normal distribution in R

Tags: r, random, sampling, resampling

I'm trying to first extract all values `<= -4` (call these `p1`) from a `mother` normal distribution. Then, randomly sample 50 of `p1`s with replacement according to their probability of being selected in the `mother` (call these 50s `p2`). For example, `-4` is more likely to be selected than `-6` which is further into the tail area.

I was wondering if my R code below correctly captures what I described above?

```
mother <- rnorm(1e6)
p1 <- mother[mother <= -4]
p2 <- sample(p1, 50, replace = T) # How can I define probability of being selected here?
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use function `sample` argument `prob`. Quoting from `help("sample")`:

> prob  a vector of probability weights for obtaining the elements of
>   the vector being sampled.

And in the section `Details`:

> The optional prob argument can be used to give a vector of weights for
>   obtaining the elements of the vector being sampled. They need not sum
>   to one, but they should be non-negative and not all zero.

So you must be careful, the more distant from the mean value the smaller the probabilities, the normal distribution drops to small values of probability very quickly.

```
set.seed(1315)    # Make the results reproducible

mother <- rnorm(1e6)
p1 <- mother[mother <= -4]

p2 <- sample(p1, 50, replace = T, prob = pnorm(p1))
```

You can see that it worked with the histogram.

```
hist(p2)
```

Comment: @rnorouzian Mine assumes a normal distribution, TUSHAr uses the uniform distribution.

Comment: @rnorouzian I'm getting an error, `Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) :   incorrect number of probabilities`.

Comment: @rnorouzian Yes, and with the example dataset it is, `mean(p1)` returns `[1] -4.208714`, `mean(p2)` returns `[1] -4.125671`.

Comment: @rnorouzian Yes, it would. The bigger the `sd` the bigger the effect.

Comment: @rnorouzian I have tried `sd = 100`, with the same `set.seed(1315)` and the values of the means were `-82.42206` and `-4.199209`, respectively for `p1` and `p2`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas just confused here, how would `pnorm(p1)` result in the probabilities of the values getting selected from `mother`?

Comment: I don't think this method correctly samples from the normal distribution (conditional on x <= -4). `p1` should *already* reflect the relative probabilities of say, -5 < x <= -4 compared to -6 < x <= -5. By sampling again from `p1`, using pdf(x) as sampling weights, you double down on that difference, exaggerating it.

Comment: For simulating regression to the mean, I've seen simulations that use bivariate normals - you generate random bivariate normals (x, y) with a correlation less than 1 (i.e. imperfect correlation), then you can look at points with x <= -4 and see what y looks like. Don't have time for a full answer but `MASS::mvrnorm()` can generate bivariate normal samples.

Comment: @TUSHAr Not selected from `mother`, from `p1`.

Comment: @Marius, I understand your time limitation, but can you please confirm if the following is what you mean:  `rmat <- matrix(c(1, .5, .5, 1), 2);
mu <- c(0, 0);

xy <- MASS::mvrnorm(1e6, Sigma = rmat, mu = mu); 

x <- xy[,1];
y <- xy[,2];
pre <- x[x <= -4];

pos <- y[pre];
mean(pre);
mean(pos);`

Comment: @rnorouzian I think it should be `pos <- y[x <= -4]` but otherwise that looks right. Try plotting the resulting points (possibly with fewer values and a less extreme x criterion) and it should demonstrate regression to the mean pretty well.

Comment: @Marius, regarding trying `"with fewer values"`, I guess since we are extracting some relatively extreme values (e.g., +/- 3 `sd` away from the population mean), the number of values must be large enough so that we can get some extreme values, otherwise can you please clarify by an example what do you mean by fewer values?

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier to sample from a *truncated* normal distribution in the first place?

```
truncnorm::rtruncnorm(50, a = -Inf, b = -4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
mother <- rnorm(1e6)
p1 <- mother[mother <= -4]
```

**Calculate probability of p1 getting selected from `mother`**

```
p2 <- sample(p1, 50, replace = T,prob = pnorm(p1,mean = mean(mother),sd = sd(mother)))
```